# How do I find an isomorphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Our book defines an isomorphism between varieties when there exist two maps say $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ and $\psi: W \rightarrow V$ both morphisms and $\psi \circ \phi =id_V$ and $\phi \circ \psi =id _W$. I am confused how do I find such maps in general because when I am given the maps it is one thing to check but I have no idea how to define such a map. For example

$V=V(x+y,z-1)$ and $W=V(x-z^2, y+z)$ both in $K^3$ algebraically closed field. So I guess what I know is that I want $\psi \circ \phi =(x,y,z)$ and $\phi \circ \psi =(x,y,z)$. Then I do not know that to look at. Can someone guide me through to understand how to make isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category of affine varieties over $K$ is equivalent to the category of reduced finitely generated $K$-algebras (If you wish irreducible on the variety side, you have to add integral domain at the algebra side).

So you have to show (or to find an isomorphism) $$K[x,y,z]/(x+y,z-1) \cong K[x,y,z]/(x-z^2,y+z)$$

Both are isomorphic to the polynomial ring in one variable.

So as a instruction I would suggest to find isormorphisms

$$K[x,y,z]/(x+y,z-1) \cong K[x] \cong K[z] \cong K[x,y,z]/(x-z^2,y+z)$$

and take the composite to be your desired isomorphism. Once you have done that, you will not have a problem giving the inverse isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If you sketch the varieties you'll see the projections of both to the y-axis are bijections.  The inverses of the projections can be calculated as

$\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow V(x+y, z-1): y \mapsto (-y, y, 1)$

$\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow V(x-z^2, y+z): y \mapsto (y^2, y,-y)$

So get your two morphisms by projecting one variety, then taking the inverse of the projection from the other variety.

Comment: I like the the ideal of sketching, it gave me a nice  geometric feel of what is happening. Thank you